dji android sdk indoor flying in autonomusly on click of a button
i want to fly my mavic air indoor/ gps-denied environment in a autonomous mode, my flight plan is takeoff at an attitude of 1m hover for 5 seconds, roll left 1m hover for 5 seconds and then land.
Please guide me and if you have any script then please share with me.
i used virtualstickView.java to do the same thing, the drone is taking off, hovering for few seconds and landing.
Thanks in advance
